# how to set master branch to main site and developer branch to develop site

Tags: gitlab

I'm new to gitlab and created a project in `gitlab`. Also I have 2 different sites on 2 different hosts, `www.main.com` and `www.developer.com`. What I want is:
when I connect to `main host` and run the command `git pull` `master branch` will be pulled and verse visa when I connect to `developer host` and run the command `git pull`, `developer branch` will be pulled.
how can I set master to main site and developer branch to developer site.

2 different sites would be matched with 2 different branches in gitlab

Answer (score 0):

When you issue "git pull", the default argument is the current branch. On the main host, when you first clone the repository, the "master" branch is checked out. On the developer host, you manually check out the developer branch, and git will pull from there from then on.

As [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> Default values for repository and branch are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by git-branch --track.